# Laying out edges with OGDF?

Tags: c++, qt, graph, draw, ogdf

Is it possible to lay out edges in OGDF? Does OGDF even include routing edges? Because I've been wading through the docs for days and still havent found out how to do so. Whats particularly interesting is the joining point between an edge and a node. Do I have to determine that point myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Ive found a way, and am writing this only in case someone, sometime might ask himself the same question.

You basically begin drawing an edge from the center of the node (i.e. `GA.x(e) + nodewidth/2`) and then iterarate over the list of bend points (if the edge `e` has any). Get the list of bend points with `GA.bends(e)`

Comment: `GA.bends(e)` returns null-reference in my case. Moreover after checking the code, I can't find a place where `m_bends` ivar was initialised with something meaningful. Did I miss something? I use latest version of OGDF which is 2015.05.